# CSS menu like microsofts

Tags: css

So I want to create a menu like the one on www.microsoft.com. However, I want to do it in only CSS, no scripts, and I want the menu to drop down on hover, not click. Here is what I have.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test5.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li>two</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">five</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">six</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">seven</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>eight</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">nine</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ten</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">eleven</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>`
```

**CSS:**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}    

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    background: #888;  
    list-style: none;
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-table;
    width:100%;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
}

nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; 
    text-decoration: none;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: You've just shown us your HTML and CSS. You haven't asked any questions about them. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net). This is very important to see what you want in a visual form.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you having? If you're interested in a pre-made solution... I'm sure they exist if you search for them.

Comment: I formatted your HTML and CSS for you. When posting on Stack Overflow please use spaces to indent, not tabs and use four spaces on every line of a code block.

Comment: ok thank you paul, i want to limit to one drop down menu, and i want to make that menu appear when the cursor hovers over a section, something like on www.microsoft.com, without clicking, something like this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/11/25/overlay-effect-menu/ without any scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for it was a little hard to figure out exactly what you wanted, I made an example for you, be sure to check in the browsers you need that the position:absolute works for you: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vkzg/

```
links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.
```

At the very least hopefully you can build from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/3EZLp/1/

html:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="navBar">
       <div class="navItemArea">
           <div class="navItem">Home</div>
           <div class="navUnder">
               Put more stuff here
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="navItemArea">
          <div class="navItem">About</div>
          <div class="navUnder">
              More stuff
          </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS in Jsfiddle.